# MySQL joins: displaying all rows in a table whilst using "where" clause

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables:

`slots` = id, time

`child` = id, parent_id, name, form

`parent` = id, name, contact_details

`teacher` = id, name, subject

`appointments` = id, child_id, slot

I'm using the following code to display a list of bookable appointment times:

```
SELECT s.id, DATE_FORMAT( s.time,  '%l:%i' ) AS TIME, p.name
FROM slots AS s
LEFT JOIN appointments AS a ON a.slot = s.id
LEFT JOIN child AS c ON a.child_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN parent AS p ON c.parent_id = p.id
```

This displays a list of all of my appointment slots and a few with parent names.

What I'd like to do is, *for a specific teacher*, **display a list of all appointment slots, and if some have been filled, I'd like to show the name of the parent of the child who has booked that slot**.

For example,

**Miss Broomfield's Appointments:**

```
id  TIME    name
1   4:00    Parent One
2   4:05    NULL
3   4:10    Parent Two
4   4:15    NULL
5   4:20    NULL
6   4:25    NULL
7   4:30    NULL
```

Is this possible? I've tried using a WHERE clause but that simply displays the booked appointments rather than the full list of times available.

I thus realised that I'm fairly sure I've got my JOINs entirely wrong!

---

**UPDATE: slots table looks like this:**

```
SQL result

Host: localhost
Generation Time: Mar 05, 2012 at 11:43 AM
Generated by: phpMyAdmin 3.4.9 / MySQL 5.5.20
SQL query: SELECT * FROM `slots` LIMIT 0, 30 ; 
Rows: 30

id  time
1   2012-03-15 16:00:00
2   2012-03-15 16:05:00
3   2012-03-15 16:10:00
4   2012-03-15 16:15:00
5   2012-03-15 16:20:00
6   2012-03-15 16:25:00
7   2012-03-15 16:30:00
8   2012-03-15 16:35:00
9   2012-03-15 16:40:00
10  2012-03-15 16:45:00
11  2012-03-15 16:50:00
12  2012-03-15 16:55:00
13  2012-03-15 17:00:00
14  2012-03-15 17:05:00
15  2012-03-15 17:10:00
16  2012-03-15 17:15:00
17  2012-03-15 17:20:00
18  2012-03-15 17:25:00
19  2012-03-15 17:50:00
20  2012-03-15 17:55:00
```

---

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you show the query you have tried? Looks like it should work - what's in the "appointments" table?
Also, is there a reason you're using outer joins between appointment, children and parents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OR you could put the following in the WHERE

`WHERE appointments.teacher_id =$teacher OR appointments.teacher_id IS NULL`

Answer (score 1):

An answer from a friend in IRC seems to have done the trick:

```
SELECT s.id, DATE_FORMAT( s.time,  '%l:%i' ) AS time, p.name
FROM slots AS s
LEFT JOIN appointments AS a ON a.slot = s.id
AND teacher_id =$teacher
LEFT JOIN child AS c ON a.child_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN parent AS p ON c.parent_id = p.id
```

The **AND** line is the important one!